# jquery ui drag&drop and margin

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, margin

When I put a margin on my draggable element, the droppable element behave in a weird way. Check out [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWbfb/1/) by dragging the element on the right.

HTML

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag on the right, then try to drag over</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      hoverClass: "drop-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

CSS

```
#draggable { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 300px 10px 10px 0; 
}
#droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
.drop-hover{
    border: 3px solid #F00;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about positioning then try:

```
position: absolute;
top:300px;
```

Comment: I also have the same problem on firefox. If you drag the element on the right, the drop element accept it even if it's not inside it. And if you try to bring the element over it then it don't accept it.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it. I can drag the draggable element how and where i want and nothing special or weird is happening.

Comment: Ok i removed the margin, and now i get the problematic. Now is the question, why do u want to have margin on a draggable element?

Comment: Apparently there is a bug in JQuery UI. I need this margin to place my different draggable element at the right position. I could use a parent div to do this.